# How can i provide a seperator to the snmp traps in my database?

Tags: python, mysql, snmp, pysnmp, snmp-trap

I have a code that receives snmp traps.
When the new traps come, i will save the output in database, as row data.
Traps are coming one after another.
In database they are mixed. it's confusing which trap values ​​it belongs to i cannot understand.
What can i do for it, how can i seperate one trap from another in database?
Here is my code

```
def cbFun(snmpEngine, stateReference, contextEngineId, contextName, varBinds,
          cbCtx):
    print('\n{0}New trap message received on {1} {0}'.format(
        '-' * 20,
        datetime.now().strftime('%d-%b-%Y at %H:%M:%S')))
    execContext = snmpEngine.observer.getExecutionContext(
            'rfc3412.receiveMessage:request')
    print('Trap is coming from %s:%s' % execContext['transportAddress'])
    for name, val in varBinds:
        print('{0} = {1}'.format(name.prettyPrint(), val.prettyPrint()))
        sql = "INSERT INTO snmp_log (name_oid, value_oid, date) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
        now = datetime.now()
        dt_string = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S")
        val = (name.prettyPrint(), val.prettyPrint(), dt_string)
        cursor.execute(sql, val)
        connection.commit()
    print('{0}Trap message ends{0}\n'.format('-' * 20))
```

Comment: You could save the transportAddress along with the other trapinfo in your database as well. Then you have the option to identify which trap belongs to which ip.

Comment: how can i save it??

Comment: Add a column more to you database, then use execContext['transportAddress'] which must be the IP the traps is comming from.

Comment: Each SNMP messages has a unique message ID (and request ID for v2/v3) (by its sender), so you should use source IP + ID(s) as primary key in your table.

Comment: You mean snmp engine id?